# Ant's global property WEBLOGIC_HOME in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant, weblogic

Ant in Eclipse has the global property WEBLOGIC_HOME but while it gives a correct tooltip in the editor it doesn't work in a build script, e.g.

```
<taskdef name="wsdlc" classname="weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.WsdlcTask" classpath="${WEBLOGIC_HOME}\server\lib\weblogic.jar" />
```

gives: build failed: wsdlctask cannot be found.

When I replace `${WEBLOGIC_HOME}` with `C:\bea\wlserver_10.3` or define my own global property there is no problem.

So nothing to worry about, but I was wondering, why does such a strange behaviour exist?

Comment: You wrote "still strange that my own global property works, and theirs doesn't". But I think that theirs do work **inside** Eclipse.

Comment: Aha, inside Eclipse but not inside an Ant build script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your workspace preferences in *Ant > Runtime > Properties*, I guess that you'll find out a WEBLOGIC_HOME property. This property is automatically added by the Weblogic plugin for Eclipse using the configuration defined in *Server > Runtime Environments*.

Not sure it's a good thing. First, I don't like when things happen in my back without being notified. Then, it make the build.xml not portable outside Eclipse. To avoid that, define your own [property](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) if necessary.

Comment: Correct, still strange that my own global property works, and theirs doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and i solve it.

The solution is to go execute the ant task as this :

- in the eclipse outline tab, click right on the task and choose "2 Ant build", the "Edit Configuration" is displayed; click on Classpath tab and Add External JARS. Add weblogic.jar jar from weblogic server lib folder.

last click on up button to make weblogic.jar in the first position.